# LinearLayout weightsum not working with image

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-layout-weight

I have a `LinearLayout` with `weightSum` 10 which has 2 child `LinearLayout` with `layout_weight` 4 and 6. It works fine when background is color or nothing. But the problem occurs when I set a background image. What can be the problem and solution?

Working code:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"

    android:weightSum="10" >

 <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="4"
        android:background="@color/Blue"
 >

    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="6"
        android:background="@color/new_back"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="10" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="5"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="99" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="33"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/idbtnCustomers"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/customer" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Chemist"
                    android:textColor="#000000" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="33"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/idbtnOrder"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/order" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Order"
                    android:textColor="#000000" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="33"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/idbtnItemStatus"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/item_status" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Item Status"
                    android:textColor="#000000" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="5"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="99" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="33"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/idbtnNotification"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/notification" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Notification"
                    android:textColor="#000000" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="33"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/idbtnAttendance"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/attendance" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Attendance"
                    android:textColor="#000000" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="33"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/idbtnExpenceClaim"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/expence_clain" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Exp. Claim"
                    android:textColor="#000000" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Problematic code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"

    android:weightSum="10" >

 <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="4"
        android:background="@drawable/top_menu"
 >

    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="6"
        android:background="@color/new_back"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="10" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="5"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="99" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="33"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/idbtnCustomers"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/customer" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Chemist"
                    android:textColor="#000000" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="33"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/idbtnOrder"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/order" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Order"
                    android:textColor="#000000" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="33"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/idbtnItemStatus"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/item_status" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Item Status"
                    android:textColor="#000000" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="5"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="99" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="33"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/idbtnNotification"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/notification" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Notification"
                    android:textColor="#000000" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="33"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/idbtnAttendance"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/attendance" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Attendance"
                    android:textColor="#000000" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="33"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/idbtnExpenceClaim"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/expence_clain" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Exp. Claim"
                    android:textColor="#000000" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: dude its working find with my side i use ic_launcher image as a backrgound image one first linear layout and also for all images i paste my code below u just take one xml and see once

Answer (score 1):

You need to understand how weight works. Weight will assign **remaining** space **after** the measure has been passed. If your image is **wrapping its contents** and it uses all the space, the remaining unused space (none) will be distributed based on weights. You have to adjust your containers and read about [Linear Layout weight.](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="10" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="4"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher" >
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="6"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="10" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="5"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="99" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="33"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/idbtnCustomers"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Chemist"
                    android:textColor="#000000" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="33"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/idbtnOrder"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Order"
                    android:textColor="#000000" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="33"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/idbtnItemStatus"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Item Status"
                    android:textColor="#000000" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="5"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="99" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="33"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/idbtnNotification"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Notification"
                    android:textColor="#000000" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="33"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/idbtnAttendance"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Attendance"
                    android:textColor="#000000" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="33"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/idbtnExpenceClaim"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Exp. Claim"
                    android:textColor="#000000" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution! The problem was with layout theme set in eclipse for that particular xml file. Theme was set to `Theme.NoTitleBar` in that xml file. I switched it to default `AppTheme` which is `Theme.Light`, now it works. :)

Answer (score 0):

This is a common misunderstanding about `layout_weight`. Rather than divide the total space of parent view based on each item's `weight`, it is the **Extra Space** that is divided.

As the official document says about [layout weight](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear.html#Weight) and I quote:

> LinearLayout also supports assigning a weight to individual children with the android:layout_weight attribute. This attribute assigns an "importance" value to a view in terms of how much space is should occupy on the screen. A larger weight value allows it to expand to fill any remaining space in the parent view. Child views can specify a weight value, and then any remaining space in the view group is assigned to children in the proportion of their declared weight. Default weight is zero.

In your case, set the `layout_height` to `0dp` means `wrap_content`, since the image is large enough, it occupies almost all the space of the parent view, which leads to no **Extra space** to be divided based on `layout_weight`. Since the `wrap_content` for pure color is just 1dp, it works fine since there is enough extra space.

To sum up, if you want the `layout_weight` to work like you expected, each view should be less than its weight of parent view.

To fix it, just wrap the `weight=4` view into a new `LinearLayout` with weight set to 4.